# How to add concave area to object in Blender

Tags: blender

I am currently modelling a very specific door handle, a photo of which is below.

I am trying to figure out how to add the concave area seen on the side of the handle, any ideas welcome as I am drawing a blank here.
[image: door handle]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi, @datenwolf, thank you for your comment and interest as well as your lack of explanation as to why it is off topic since I added the tag "blender", and the tag "blender" is available to use.
If I had known blender.stackexchange.com existed, don't you think I'd used it? May I suggest next time you are nicer in your approach, engage with the user and educate the user instead of sending a comment of the likes you just sent? Yours always truly

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site about programming and software development. The "blender" tag on StackOverflow is related to programming Blender plugins and scripts. You're asking about how to model something in Blender. This is not programming, this is content creation and doesn't belong here. I've put the link to the StackExchange network site focused entirely on Blender right into the closing comment.

Comment: Thank you @datenwolf, very much appreciated and the info provided now makes absolute sense. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy with the [boolean modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html)

you basically modell the part that would fill the concave area (in your case thats a sphere streched on one axis) and then do a boolean operation (difference) on your handle and the sphere

Comment: Thank you @Kamil. This is the first thing I thought of using but I was under the impression boolean operations created bad geometry, and being new to 3D and blender I may have taken this a little too seriously :) thanks again for the help

Comment: That is correct. However, bad geometry isnt a big issue for solid objects that won't change their shape in animations (changing position, location or scale is still going to work). If you really wanted to you could retopologize the object afterwards (that way the shape of the object will stay *almost* the same but the geometry will improve)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info @Kamil